# How to use Stokes Theorem twice to simplify integral?

Tags: real-analysis, stokes-theorem

I am trying to compute the integral $\iint_{\partial D} \langle\operatorname{curl}F,n\rangle \,dS$ where $D=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R} : \frac{x^2}{4}+\frac{y^2}{9}+\frac{z^2}{16}<1\}$ and $F(x,y,z)=(\cos(x\sin(z))+y^3, xy, \cos(x\sin(z\textrm{e}^y))$.

I am given the hint that applying Stokes Thm twice would simplify the surface of integration.

I found that $\operatorname{curl}F=(-xz \textrm{e}^y \cos(z\textrm{e}^y) \sin(x\sin(z\textrm{e}^y)), -x \cos(z)\sin(x\sin(z)) + \sin(z\textrm{e}^y) \sin(x\sin(z\textrm{e}^y)), y).$

I'm not sure where to go from here though; I know I need to find a normal vector and probably a paramaterization of $D$ but I'm not sure how. I'm also unsure how I would apply Stokes twice?

Comment: Since $\delta D$ is a closed surface do you should have the integral is zero? Use divergence theorem (sometimes called Stoke's Theorem) and the fact that $div(curl)F=0$.

Comment: Alternatively you could split the sphere into two hemispheres and apply Stoke's theorem to both, resulting in the same integral taken along the same circle but in opposite directions, leading to a net result of $0.$

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\text{right: } & \iint_{\partial D} \langle \operatorname{curl}F,n\rangle \, dS \\ {} \\ \text{wrong: } & \iint_{\partial D} <\textrm{curl}F,n>dS
\end{align}
$$ Using `\mathrm{curl}F` instead of `\operatorname{curl}F` is the cause of the lack of proper spacing. With the latter usage, the horizontal spacing varies with the context. And I added a small space to separate $dS$ from the rest. And $\langle a,b\rangle$ differs from $<a,b>. \qquad$